How can I make an instance always be the same as another instance if not copied? (if an instance is changed than the other changes)
I'm working on a project (the very complex task of a computer emulator) and I need to make a ConnectedPin instance always be the same as another (kind of like how multiple dict objects can be the same as one another where if one changes they all change).
I really can't figure out how dict works to make all instances that are the same connect.
I didn't try much since my ideas wouldn't work for my emulator's intentions.

Turns out this was a duplicate

dict objects work just like any other type of object (including user-defined types) in this regard, so it really isn't clear what exactly the issue is, you should provide a [mcve]

And I highly suggest not doing anything in the linked duplicate.

@juanpa.arrivillaga No i already did (and it worked really well)

@juanpa.arrivillaga Also i have had trouble with dict objects (mostly cause i forgot about D.copy()) before
